# Notifications from user to user with Laravel/Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, laravel

I'm using Laravel as my backend and Android as my front end. In my mobile app, I need to send notifications when clicking on a card view to alert the other user. These users will be associted to each other in database tables. So do I have to work with laravel or android for this part? 
PS: I am using MySQL, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: First, you have to basic knowledge that how the notification is work. you should know the basic flow.   you can check here: https://github.com/laravel-notification-channels/pusher-push-notifications . Also post your code what did you implement

Comment: I didn't start yet , but does this pusher allows me to send notifications from user to user? and call it as an API in my Android app?

Comment: yes you can send notification through pusher web/ios/android you can 
check here for device https://pusher.com/beams

Answer (score 0):

you can use a great package https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification;

or by php
For Android

```php
<?php
public static

function send_notification_android($device_id, $android_ids, $message, $title)
    {
    $result = array();
    $payload = array();
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $api_key = 'AAAA3KgUuXA:APA91bEfEs8UHGIzxVPPAxnNAAwaOIfHw82LTJ2PzNjh4P-kDJGUx5KAtqHmcNixyslW087G3dWfNVwMrfmvj9tHKmEoC5OB3NW6CZT_H4oGFv_QvTZWN9aEr2IfZ3QOixfTaF0VTac9';
    $result['title'] = $title;
    $result['body'] = $message;
    $fields = array(
        'to' => $android_ids,
        'data' => $result
    );
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . $api_key,
        'Authorization: key=' . $api_key,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE)
        {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }

    curl_close($ch);
    if (!empty($result))
        {
        return false;
        }
      else
        {
        return true;
        }
    }



IOS



<?php
public

function send_push_notification($deviceToken, $badges, $msg, $data)
    {
    $key = public_path() . '/pushcert12.pem';
    $url = "ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195";

    // $url = 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195'; // for development

    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $key);
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', 'ThreatAlert');
    $fp = stream_socket_client($url, $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
    $message = $msg;
    $body['aps'] = array(
        'alert' => $message,
        'badge' => intval($badges) ,
        'sound' => 'default',
        'data' => ''
    );
    $payload = json_encode($body);
    $deviceToken = str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken);
    try
        {
        $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload . chr(3) . pack('n', 4) . pack('N', $deviceToken) . chr(4) . pack('n', 4) . pack('N', time() + 86400) . chr(5) . pack('n', 1) . chr(10);
        $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
        if (!$result)
            {
            $res = 0;
            }
          else
            {
            $res = 1;
            }

        $retmsg = $res;
        }

    catch(Exception $eee)
        {
        $this->log('Message Push - ' . $eee);
        }

    fclose($fp);
    $retmsg = '<br />' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . ' Connection closed to APNS' . PHP_EOL;
    }
```